# How can I make the div reappear again, after the person chose to hide the div? (javascript-related)

Tags: javascript

So I am javascript illiterate, but I did find this useful code online:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readCookie( cName )
{
  var v;

  return decodeURIComponent( ( v = ( document.cookie || "" ).match( "(^|\\s)" + cName + "=([^;$]+)" ) ) ? v[ 2 ] : "" );
}

function setCookie( cName, cValue, life, cPath, cDomain, cSecure )
{
 var dt = new Date(), 
     expSecs = ( expSecs = life.toString().match( /\bsecs\s*=\s*(\d+)/i ) ) ? Number( expSecs[ 1 ] ) : 0,
     params = ( life ? ( ";expires=" + new Date( expSecs ? ( dt.setTime( dt.getTime() + expSecs * 1000 ) )                                                          : ( dt.setDate( dt.getDate() + life) ) ).toUTCString() ) : "" )
            + ( cPath ? (";path=" + cPath) : "" )
            + ( cDomain ? ";domain=" + cDomain : "" )
            + ( cSecure ? ";secure" : "" );

 document.cookie = cName + "=" + encodeURIComponent( cValue ) + params;

 return readCookie( cName );
}

if( readCookie( "close" ) )
{
  document.getElementById("thing").style.display="none";
}

function close_thing()
{
  document.getElementById("thing").style.display="none";
  setCookie( "close", "true", 20 );
}
</script>
```

It works with this div

```
<div id="thing">
<div id="close_stuff" onclick="close_thing();"><a href="#">Close this</a></div>
</div>
```

My problem is, if I want my div to contain content, which the user can close if he/she wishes. However, I want the div to reappear, when I put new content into the div.

Is there a way I could do this manually? Like rename all the "close_thing" to "klose_thing", or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you put the content in value property of cookie and on document load match the content if it does not matches then open the div?

Comment: when/how will you put a new content into the div ? after the page was already rendered ? in such a case you'll need to use ajax to pull data from the server.

Comment: Deepesh, that seems like an awesome idea. Can you show me how to do that? Like I said, I know nothing about javascript. Alfa, the new content would be inside the div. It's that simple (I've tried).

Comment: From javascript ... `document.getElementById("close").style.display = "auto"` or `"block"` ... will do the trick

Comment: Memo, would I put that after the function(){document.getElementById("thing").style.display="none";
  setCookie( "close", "true", 20 );}? Or where in the code, for that matter? (As I said, I'm javascript illiterate :( )

Comment: So I added in your code, memosdp, {document.getElementById("close").style.display = "auto";} after the function close_thing, and then added a couple letters into the div (thereby, adding new stuff to the div), and my div still doesn't reappear.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Adding another function will do this for you. Set the display property to block.

```
function show_thing()
{
  document.getElementById("thing").style.display="block";
}
```

Then call show_thing function display the div again.

Comment: So these are the last two lines in my javascript code: 
function close_bottom_stuff()
{
  document.getElementById("bottom_stuff").style.display="none";
  setCookie( "closedStuff", "true", 30 );
}
function show_bottom_stuff()
{
  document.getElementById("bottom_stuff").style.display="block";
}
</script>

I'm in incognito mode in chrome right now, and after I added in a bunch of letters, the div still doesn't show up. You said "Then call show_thing function display the div again". How do I call the show_thing function to display the div again?

Comment: You debug in "incognito mode"? Why is that? O.O

Anyway if you want to show the hidden div when you type some letters somewhere, you can try [onfocus event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, this whole example probably isn't making sense because it's hard for me to elaborate what I'm trying to do. Basically, I have to test in incognito, because when you click the "Close this", it hides the div for 20 days (I think), because its stored in the cache. I don't want to keep clearing my cache, in testing, so I just keep reopening new incognito windows on Chrome to test.

Anyhow, if this still isn't making sense to you, I can email you (found it on your site) the specifics, since I'm being intentionally vague. I fully intend on giving you a check, if you want to help ^^.

Comment: Well, you need to keep reading and experiment dear. Keep coding and post questions, there are 1000's of people here to help. Do not give up...